# Calling registered event callback function based on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Say I have a simple button like:

```
<button id='test'>ClickME</button>
```

on which through some script (provided by some other person), a click event is registered, like this:

```
$('#test').on('click', function(){
      alert('click 1');  //Some lines of code
});
```

Later on the page load, I ran my script on top of it, in which I wanted to perform some actions on the same button click. In the script, I wrote something like:

```
$('#test').on('click', function(){
      alert('click 2');   //Some lines of code
});
```

In this case, when I click on the button, I am getting two alerts which is understandable.

What I wanted to achieve is, First "click 2" should be alerted and in the same code, based on some condition, I may or may not call the previously registered function, i.e. "click 1" alert. I have no clue whether we can achieve such things and if yes, how can I prevent execution of already registered event?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unbind all previous event handlers from an element. Before that, you can store what they were. This allows you to write code like:

```
// not your code
$('#test').on('click', function(){
      alert('click 1');  //Some lines of code
});

// your code
var prevHandler = $._data($("#test")[0], "events").click[0].handler;

$('#test').off('click');

$('#test').on('click', function(){
      alert('click 2');   //Some lines of code
      if (Math.random() > 0.5)
          prevHandler();
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ugefofLs/

Comment: Awesome! One thing to clarify, is it only possible using jquery or can be done via plain javascript.

Comment: Glad I can help! jQuery is ultimately written in javascript, so yes, it is possible; however, it will probably be even more convoluted and less portable. One of the best things about jQuery is that it is community tested for different browsers, so you are pretty much guaranteed it will work. If you want to look up jQuery's implementation, then I think it is in https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js on the line 857.

Answer (score 1):

Both handlers will run, the jQuery event model allows multiple handlers on one element, therefore a later handler does not override an older handler.

[The handlers will execute in the order in which they were bound](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#entry-longdesc).

I suggest you merge the two code block something like this:

```
$('#test').on('click', function(){
      alert('click 2');   //Some lines of code
   if (some condition){
    alert('click 1');  //Some lines of code
   }  

});
```

Comment: I am not allowed to make changes in script provided by others!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know whether or not other events have been registered, and still want to make sure only your event fires, you can use jQuerys `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to only allow your event to be run.

> `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`
>
> Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.Keeps the rest of the handlers from

See the code and snippet below

```js
//Change this to false to let both registrered events run
var preventOtherClickEvents = true;

var onClick = function(event) {
  if (preventOtherClickEvents) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }

  alert('First event handler');
};

var onClickSecond = function() {
  alert('Second event handler');
};

$('#button').on('click', onClick);

$('#button').on('click', onClickSecond);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />
```

Comment: Thats good to know about `stopImmediatePropagation()`, but i am not allowed to make changes in the script provided by others. All i can do is make some workaround in my script. anyways thanks!.. :)

Comment: Thats the point of this script, you don't have to change any others since you can write your own code and stop other code from running, without having to change it! =)